# How does AppKit decide whether to render a window's title and toolbar greyed out, and is this configurable?

Tags: macos, nswindow, appkit, nstoolbar

I have an NSWindow A that I do not want to become the key window if it has a [child window](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419152-addchildwindow?language=objc) B on screen. Implementing this hackily, by overriding window A's `windowDidBecomeKey:` to call window B's `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` method works roughly as I'd like, and results in windows that look like this, which is what I want them to look like:

[image]

However, I don't want window A to become key temporarily: I do not want it to become key at all.

If I instead override window A's `canBecomeKeyWindow` method to return `NO` when window B is present, then everything works exactly as I'd like, EXCEPT that window A's title and toolbar are now rendered greyed out, and I do not want them to be:

[image]

Clicks on the toolbar items still work immediately, so the items are (correctly) not disabled: only their labels are greyed out.

Note that with the hacky solution *both* windows are rendered with not-greyed out titles simultaneously, so it does *not* appear to be the case that NSWindow titles and toolbars are rendered greyed out whenever they are not the key window (unlike, say, the window close icon, which appears only to be coloured in when the window is key).

**Why does returning `NO` from `canBecomeKeyWindow` cause the title and toolbar to be rendered greyed out, and is it possible to change this behaviour so that the window renders normally?**

Comment: Please describe the behaviour you want. Do you want a greyed out title? clickable buttons? is window B modal, a dialog, a panel?

Comment: @Willeke Window B is neither modal, nor a dialog. It's just a regular NSWindow [child window](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419152-addchildwindow?language=objc). I do not want a greyed out title. The buttons are currently always clickable and I want them to remain so.

Comment: @Willeke I want the window to look like a normal, active window. Currently it looks as if the toolbar is disabled (which it is not).

Comment: @Willeke I added images, which hopefully make it clearer what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by both:

1. returning NO from Window A's `canBecomeKeyWindow` *and*
2. returning NO from Window B's `canBecomeMainWindow`.

I still don't know the answer to how AppKit decides whether to render the toolbar and title as active. My guess is that it renders both the main and key windows as active, and windows that are neither key nor main as inactive. If someone can give a more authoritative answer, I will make that the accepted answer.